# Open Google Play using alert confirm button

Tags: ionic2, google-play, alert

Can you explain me how to launch the Google Play app using the alert confirm button?

Here's the code:

```
let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Nouvelle mise a jour disponible',
  message: 'Version ameliorer de eLahiya disponible, voulez vous la telecharger?',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Plus tard',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Disagree clicked');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Mise a jour',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Agree clicked');
        window.open("play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>", '_system', 'location=yes')//
      }
    }
  ]
});
confirm.present();
```

I want my app to open my app's page on the playstore, how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this works perfectly for me:

```
window.open('market://details?id=your.package.name', '_system');
```

This is for Android though. For others:

```
IOS: itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/<appId>
Amazon: amzn://apps/android?p=<appPackageId>
```

Let me know if it works for you. Look into [cordova-plugin-market](https://github.com/xmartlabs/cordova-plugin-market) as an alternative if that does not work.

Answer (score 5):

Ionic native has a plugin to open an app's page in the market place. Here it is [cordova-plugin-market](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/market/)

Use this command to install this plugin,

```
 ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-market
 npm install --save @ionic-native/market
```

Usage,

```
import { Market } from '@ionic-native/market';

constructor(private market: Market) { }

...

this.market.open('your.package.name');
```